# Installing Sage on a Linux machine that has Anaconda causes an error, but would like to have both

Tags: installation, anaconda, sage

So I ran into the same problem as this question asker's: https://ask.sagemath.org/question/35132/how-do-i-solve-this-installation-problem/

The solution seems to be effectively to delete the line

```
export PATH="/home/addem/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

from the `.bashrc` file, but then I won't be able to use Anaconda.  Is there any way to have access to both softwares on the same computer?  This question seems to have been asked in a couple places but never with an answer.

Comment: I don't know if you can easily do both at the same time without a little care.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem would be to install SageMath via Conda.

Install instructions: https://wiki.sagemath.org/Conda

Or, instead of including the line

`export PATH="/home/addem/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

in your `.bashrc`, you could include this line

`alias condapath='export PATH="/home/addem/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"'`

and run `condapath` to change the PATH only when you want to use conda.

Or use an alias to set a conda-less PATH, to run before running Sage.